# Work with Excel in VB.net fails without reason

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-2010, export-to-excel

below code is about to export to excel file.
Visual Studio sends the error in the picture.
What is wrong with this code?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Module Module3
    Public Sub OOO()
        Dim excel As Application = New Application
        Dim workbook As Workbook = New Workbook
        Dim worksheet As Worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
        worksheet.Name = "Export as Excel Project"
        worksheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Value1"
        worksheet.Cells(2, 1) = "Value2"
        worksheet.SaveAs("d:\Actor.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault)
        workbook.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to be closing your instance of Excel at the end of the proc.

Comment: Thanks. I remove the closing line from the code. But no luck!

Comment: What does "Doesn't run it" mean? 
How do we reproduce your issue?

Comment: Apparently you think that your `Application` is `Excel.Application`. [It is not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Whereas in VBA, from where you copied that code, it is, because nothing else resolves to `Application`.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not application? could you please explain more clear? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of scope resolution? Put the caret inside the word `Application` and press F12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong starting by first Dim excel line. You expect that would be an Excel.Application but it is not, it is System.Windows.Application (as I understand from error window). If that line were correct, next line is trying to create an unrelated Workbook object. Instead try:

```
Sub Main
    Dim xl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = CType(workbook.ActiveSheet, Worksheet)
    worksheet.Name = "Export as Excel Project"
    worksheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Value1"
    worksheet.Cells(2, 1) = "Value2"
    worksheet.SaveAs("d:\Actor.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault)
    workbook.Close()
    xl.Quit()
End Sub
```

Note that file extension is XLSX, not XLS for current versions of Excel (for a long time really, and Excel wouldn't open it without a warning if you happen to save as XLS).